# Extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-d}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146437/whats-the-difference-between-mathbbq-sqrt-d-and-mathbbq-sqrt-d)

Let
$$\mathbb Q[i]=\{a+ib|a, b\in \mathbb Q\}$$
Any nonzero element $a+ib\in\mathbb{Q}[i]$ has an inverse element because
$$\frac{1}{a+ib}=\frac{a-ib}{a^2+b^2}\in\mathbb{Q}.$$

Is it true that $\mathbb{Q}(i)=\mathbb{Q}[i]$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is true. Of course, this follows from your explicit description of the inverse.

Also, $i$ has the minimal polynomial $X^2+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and therefore the extension $\mathbb{Q}[i]|\mathbb{Q}$ is finite. Then it follows $\mathbb{Q}(i)=\mathbb{Q}[i]$. This is a general result for finite extensions.

Comment: Why from $[\mathbb{Q}[i]:\mathbb{Q}]<\infty$ follows $\mathbb{Q}[i]=\mathbb{Q}(i)$?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. This is a general fact: if $\,\mathbb{F}\,$ is any field and $\,\alpha\,$ is an element in some field extension, then $\,\alpha\,$ is algebraic over $\,\mathbb{F}\,$ iff $\,\mathbb{F}[\alpha]=\mathbb{F}(\alpha)\,$ .

As $\,i\,$ is a root of the rational pol. $\,x^2+1\,$ , it is alg. over the rationals...

Comment: ***added*** The proof of the above is short and easy:

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for exactly the reason you cited.