# Isn't $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^2+1)\cong \mathbb Q[i]$ wrong and should be $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^2+1)\cong \mathbb Q(i)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Isn't $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^2+1)\cong \mathbb Q[i]$ wrong and should be $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^2+1)\cong \mathbb Q(i)$ ?

Indeed, $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^2+1)$ is a field whereas $\mathbb Q[i]$ is a ring (is the Fraction ring of $\mathbb Q(i)$).

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ is in fact a field, since $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: Actually $\Bbb Q [i]$ happens to be a field, thus it coincides with $\Bbb Q (i)$

Comment: For any $\;a\in\Bbb C\;$ , we have that $\Bbb Q[a]=\Bbb Q(a)\iff a\;$ is algebraic over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ . You can also change $\;\Bbb Q\;$ and use your favourite field and its algebraic closure.

Comment: A field *is* a ring, in case that is worrying you for some reason.

Comment: Fields are also rings

Comment: @Crostul : Really ? but $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^2+1)=\{aX+b+(X^2+1)\mid a,b\in \mathbb Q\}$. But why division is defined ? for example, what is $\frac{X+1}{X+2}$ ? (because division doesn't look defined)

Comment: @user623855 Your description of that quotient is pretty weak...to say the very least. You should check that carefully

Comment: @PaulK : Why the fact that $i^2=-1$ implies that $\mathbb Q[i]$ is a field ?

Comment: @DonAntonio: what do you mean ? I'm not correct ?

Comment: To see why $i^2=-1$ implies $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ is a field, see the first comment by @DonAntonio

Comment: @user623855 Whether you're wrong or not depends on what *you* understand by what you wrote. For example, the elements in $\;\Bbb Q[X]/\langle X^2+1\rangle\;$ are *not* polynomials but equivalence classes. If this is clear to you then yes, you're right. And if you do understand this then it is more usual to write those elements in other way. For example, like $\;2x+1\;$ , where $\;x=X+\langle X^2+1\rangle\;$ , say., and etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes I know. I should have written $[X]$ instead of $X$. So what is $\frac{[X+1]}{[X+2]}$ ?

Comment: @user623855: You have to use the algorithm for rationalizing the denominator. Multiply top and bottom by the conjugate of the denominator.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip: What do you mean by "conjugaute of $[X+2]$ ?

Comment: Go by analogy with what you expect it to be: $-X+2.$

Comment: That's the same thing, ring extension equals field extension here.

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha$ is a root of a *monic* polynomial $\rm\:f(x)\:$ over a domain $\rm\:D\:$ then $\rm\:D[\alpha]\:$ is a field iff $\rm\:D\:$ is a field. Ditto for arbitrary integral extensions of domains. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69987/242) is a detailed treament of the quadratic case.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your question in the comments: observe that in $\;\Bbb F:=\Bbb Q[X]/\langle X^2+1\rangle\;$ , we have that if $\;x:=Z+\langle x^2+1\rangle\;$ , then $\;x^2+1=0\implies x^2=-1\;$ , so in $\;\Bbb F\;$ we get

$$\frac1{x+2}=\frac{2-x}{4-x^2}=\frac{2-x}{4+1}=\frac15(-x+2)$$

so

$$\frac{x+1}{x+2}=(x+1)\frac1{x+2}=(x+1)\frac15(-x+2)=\frac15(-x^2+x-2)=\frac15(x-1)$$

In similar form you can do other calculation. Observe the is just hte usual operations inthe complex $\;\Bbb C\;$ , just "in disguise".