# How do I show whether this set of quadratic irrationals is a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I wasn't sure how to search for this question.

"Is this a ring? Is it unitary? Is it commutative?

$\left\{\frac{n+m\sqrt{d}}{2} : n, m \in \mathbb{Z}\ \text{both having the same parity}\right\}$, $d$ being a square - free integer (i.e. not divisible by the square of a prime)."

Is what I need to do show that this $\frac{n+m\sqrt{d}}{2}$ has all of the properties of a ring i.e. additive inverse, associativity etc? And if so, can someone help me with the additive inverse one? Because if they must always have the same parity, does that mean the additive inverse is $\frac{-n-m\sqrt{d}}{2}$?

**Additive Associativity:**

$n,m,i,j,a,b$ $\epsilon$ $\mathbb{Z}$

*From left to right:*

$\implies$ (($\frac{n+m\sqrt{d}}{2}$)+($\frac{i+j\sqrt{d}}{2}$))+($\frac{a+b\sqrt{d}}{2}$)

$\implies$ ($\frac{n+i}{2}$+$\frac{(m+j)\sqrt{d}}{2}$)+($\frac{a+b\sqrt{d}}{2}$)

$\implies$ $\frac{n+i+a}{2}$+$\frac{(m+j+b)\sqrt{d}}{2}$

*From right to left:*

$\impliedby$ ($\frac{n+m\sqrt{d}}{2}$)+(($\frac{i+j\sqrt{d}}{2}$)+($\frac{a+b\sqrt{d}}{2}$))

$\impliedby$ ($\frac{n+m\sqrt{d}}{2}$)+($\frac{i+a}{2}$+$\frac{(m+b)\sqrt{d}}{2}$)

$\impliedby$ $\frac{n+i+a}{2}$ $\frac{(n+m+b)\sqrt{d}}{2}$

**Additive Commutativity:**

$n,m,i,j$ $\epsilon$$\mathbb{Z}$

*Left to right:*

$\implies$ ($\frac{n+m\sqrt{d}}{2}$)+($\frac{i+j\sqrt{d}}{2}$)

$\implies$ $\frac{n+i}{2}$+$\frac{(m+j)\sqrt{d}}{2}$

*Right to left:*

$\impliedby$ ($\frac{i+j\sqrt{d}}{2}$)+($\frac{n+m\sqrt{d}}{2}$)

$\impliedby$ $\frac{i+n}{2}$+$\frac{(j+m)\sqrt{d}}{2}$

As $n,m,i,j$ are all intergers, the sum of these is just another integer. So these are equal also.

**Additive Identity:**

$n,m$ $\epsilon$ $\mathbb{Z}$ so we can let $n=m=0$. Putting this is gives:

$\frac{0+0\sqrt{d}}{2}$ $\implies$ 0

**Additive Inverse**

Let $V=\frac{-n+-m\sqrt{d}}{2}$ and $V'=\frac{n+m\sqrt{d}}{2}$

$V + V' \implies \frac{-n+-m\sqrt{d}}{2} + \frac{n+m\sqrt{d}}{2}$

$\implies$ $\frac{-n+n}{2} + \frac{(-m+m)\sqrt{d}}{2}$

$\implies$ $\frac{0}{2} + \frac{(0)\sqrt{d}}{2}$

$\implies$ $0 + 0$

$\implies$ $0$

This is as far as I've got so far. If anything isn't right please tell me. As I go through I'll update with the next axioms.

Here is the question as it is shown on my question sheet - I was only interested in part c. I have now finished solving this question thank you for everyone's advice and help.

[image: Original Question in Context]

Comment: That's the correct additive inverse. Have you tried all the other ring axioms?

Comment: I'm working on them currently. I've done (I think!) the additive associativity, additive commutativity and the additive identity.

Comment: Add your attempts to the question-body so we can check them.

Comment: I’m sure you meant to include the hypothesis that $d$ should be of form $4k+1$ for an integer $k$. Otherwise, your set is not closed under multiplication: $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt2}2\right)^2=\frac{3+2\sqrt2}4$, not of the correct form.

Comment: I added an answer showing a simple approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the operations on the ring, but it's natural to assume the operations are meant to be ordinary addition and multiplication of numbers. In that case, your set $R$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$, if $d\geq 0$), and the operations agree with those in $\mathbb{C}$, so we just need to check that it's a subring. That is, we need to check that $R$:

1. Is closed under addition.
2. Contains $0$.
3. Is closed under additive inverse.
4. Is closed under multiplication.
5. Contains $1$ (if you want the ring to be unitary).

The rest of the properties of rings (including commutativity) are automatically inherited from the larger ring $\mathbb{C}$ (if you don't know this fact, you should try to prove it for yourself! - or look up a proof of the "subring test").

You've already found that the additive inverse of any element of $R$ is in $R$, and $R$ contains $0 = \frac{0+0\sqrt{d}}{2}$ and $1 = \frac{2+0\sqrt{d}}{2}$, so it is unitary.

Checking closure under addition and multiplication involve more complicated computation, and indeed closure under multiplication is not true without further assumptions on $d$, as pointed out by Lubin in the comments.

Comment: I've done the multiplication one now, and I get lots of fractions, but picking one gives (njbd)/8. Now if d is a square free number, that means that it can't be divided by 8, is that correct? If it is, that means that this cannot be a ring as it fails this property. Is that right?

Comment: @Emily how did you get $(njbd)/8$? That doesn't look right... also, what do you mean by "I get lots of fractions" and "picking one"?

Comment: I’m sorry, I hate to downvote an answer, but I’m going to do it in this case. As stated, OP’s set is not a ring at all, not being closed under multiplication.

Comment: @Lubin That's fair - in defense of the answer, I didn't actually assert that the thing is a ring, and I think it's helpful to the OP to point out exactly what needs to be checked (seeing as how she wasted time carefully checking commutativity of addition). But I did make it sound like closure under multiplication should be true. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

The set is clearly a subset of the ring $\,\Bbb C\,$ so the [subring test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/40685/242) implies it is a subring if it contains $1$ and is closed under subtraction and multiplication. The first two are clear, and for the third use: $ $ hint $\,(n\!+\!m\sqrt d)/2 = \color{#c00}{(n\!-\!m)/2} + m\color{#0a0}{(1\!+\!\sqrt{d})/2} = \color{#c00}k + m\,\color{#0a0}w,\ k,m\in\Bbb Z.\,$ It is easy to show the latter forms are closed under products, using $\,\color{#0a0}{w^2} = w + (d\!-\!1)/4,\,$ and $\,(d\!-\!1)/4\in\Bbb Z\,$ by hypothesis.

Comment: But I still do not see a correction by OP requiring $d\equiv1\pmod4$.

Comment: @Lubin Likely that's just an oversight in the question statement.

Comment: In fact, @BillDubuque, OP’s first comment to AlexKruckman’s answer suggests just the contrary. I do think that OP mistranscribed the original question put to her.

Comment: Thank you for your help Bill, I have now finished solving this question with the help of Alex above previously. I have also added the full question as an image for context.